# Audio file playing twice using javascript

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a string array that stores 17 links to mp3 files. I perform a math.random() from 0-16 to select one and play it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  soundcheck = setInterval(function() {
    var audio = new Audio(audiofiles[randomInt(0,16)]);
    audio.play();
  }, 10000);
});
```

However, every 10 seconds two are randomly chosen and played. Please explain why and how I fix this.

Comment: unless that code is on the page twice, not sure how it is running twice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This code does not seem to contain the problem.

Comment: Your code isn't choosing two audios, the issue is the one that was playing isn't stopped before the new one starts playing; so you end with two audios being played at the same time.

Comment: @smarx I genunely can't identify any other part of my code related to the question at all. There isn't any other part of it related to audio either.

Comment: And you can see all the code! Imagine how hard it would be for someone on Stack Overflow to find the problem *without* the code.